# JPA mapping(joining) a table with one column that contains multiple key values to another table with each key defined

Tags: jpa

I have a scenario in which a table contains multiple key values in a single character column.  The other table has the keys as seperate columns, e.g.,

Table1 (multiple key values in a single column) Column1 value = "113908765"

Table2 (keys defined in seperate columns, as Integer values): Column1 value = 113
                                           Column2 value = 908765

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: How to join the tables,  with this scenario.  It looks like the only alternative is to write a query to either concatenate the keys from the second table to join on the first table, or split the value in the first table (substring function) and join the tables.

Answer (score 0):

that's not a normalized design, either:

- merge the split keys

..or

- split the combined key into pieces

..or

- add the merged key too

Comment: I totally agree that it is not normalized, but this is what I have to live with.  Wasn't aware of any annotations in JPA that would help with this scenario.  Looks like I'll have to settle on a JPQL query to "join" the two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer concerning the view.  That's probably the only other viable option than to write a JPQL query to join the two.